# p:ajax fires twice

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

concerning p:ajax of PrimeFaces. I have two p:ajax requests within my `<p:commandButton>`. I did `stdout` within the second method so that I can see if its triggered or not. The same (last) method is triggered twice and I don't know why. If I put only one `<p:ajax>` request into my button he fires once and if I put two `<p:ajax>` requests he fires twice.

```
<h:body style="background:#f5f5f5;">
    <h:form id="formG">
        <p:commandButton styleClass="viewButton" icon="ui-icon-search"
            value="#{msg['button.open']}" id="auftragButtonG">

            <p:ajax listener="#{auftragBean.saveIdIntoAppScope()}"  partialSubmit="true"/>
            <p:ajax listener="#{auftragBean.loadXMLData()}" partialSubmit="true"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

```
public void loadXMLData(){
    setXmlData(entireXmlData(mandantId(), getJobId()));
    System.out.println(getXmlData().size());
}
```

Anybody knows why and how I can ignore the second load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're instructing the component to fire two ajax requests on the same (default) event. One `<p:ajax>` counts as one request. In other words, the code is behaving exactly as you programmed it.

You need to solve your concrete problem differently.

1. Invoke one method which in turn delegates to the desired methods.

   ```
   <p:commandButton ... action="#{bean.methodWhichInvokesBothMethods()}" partialSubmit="true" />
   ```
2. Invoke multiple methods in one call. You can use `<f:actionListener binding>` trick for this.

   ```
   <p:commandButton ... partialSubmit="true">
       <f:actionListener binding="#{bean.method1()}" />
       <f:actionListener binding="#{bean.method2()}" />
   </p:commandButton>
   ```

Either way, the `<p:ajax>` is totally unnecessary as the `<p:commandButton>` by itself already has builtin ajax support.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)